près vs. au + près
«  Auprès (de) »  est "Composé de au (v. a-1) et de près."
Qu'est-ce que « au »  ajoute ou contribue, le cas échéant, au « près » ?
Le préfixe « au » paraît bizarre, dénué de sens pour les deux raisons suivantes.
« au » ici n'indique pas la destination, comme dans

Je voyage au Mexique où j'hiverne, pour éviter le froid.

Mais "Je voyage au près où j'hiverne, pour éviter le froid." n'a aucun sens ! « près » n'est pas une destination !
« au » paraît redondant, puisque « près  » se suffit à lui-même.

Jupiter est près de Saturne.†

Je ne perçois aucune différence entre ceci, et 'Jupiter est auprès de Saturne.'

La maison jaune est près.‡

Je ne perçois aucune différence entre ceci, et 'La maison jaune est auprès.'
† Vandeloise, Claude. Spatial Prepositions: A Case Study from French. University of Chicago Press, 1991. Page 67.
‡ Ibid, p. 70.

Sauf qu'on ne dit pas de nos jours (ça a pu se dire)  Jupiter est auprès de Saturne parce que Saturne n'est pas une personne, c'est donc Jupiter est près de Saturne qui est correct. Auprès de exprime la proximité avec une personne (Il est auprès de son père) ou au sens figuré d'une opinion ( il est bien vu auprès de son chef).

A priori, l'étymologie du TLFi citée dans la question est celle de l'adverbe "auprès" et différente de la préposition "auprès de" (qui n'est pas expliquée, mais on peut penser à une nominalisation de "près", comme dans "auparavant").

Après auprès on nomme ce qui proche. La maison jaune est près (c'est à dire pas loin), et la maison jaune est près de la maison rouge, il est auprès de son père mais il est auprès ne se dit pas (ou alors ça peut être sous-entendu *A-t-il rendu visite à son père – Oui, il est auprès (de lui). Auprès de (son père)  implique une proximité affective (il est dans sa proximité pour le soutenir, l'aider, etc...), près de signifie plus à côté de, c'est la proximité physique qui est soulignée.

@guillaume31 Nominalisation, possible (qu'on retrouverait dans le terme de marine « naviguer au près du vent » (en deux mots).  Adjectif ? comme le suggérerait l'abbé Régnier cité par Lacurne

Dans auprès, près est un nom, pas un adverbe. Le près de Saturne, ce sont ses environs. Pas nécessairement pour l'Académie: selon ceux qui ont produit cette locution.

@None bonne trouvaille, par contre je me demande si la qualification "d'adjectif" pour "près" et "loin" par l'abbé Régnier n'est pas vieillie (et on est toujours face à une définition de l'adverbe "auprès", pas de la préposition "auprès de").

@guillaume31 Vieilli plus que  sûr... s'il l'a jamais été. Je comprends qu'il s'est juste posé la question. Ou alors Lacurne a mal compris... rien dans le Dictionnaire de l'académie et pourtant il me semble que Régnier y a participé. D'ailleurs loin adjectif ! Bizarre aussi.

Je viens de jeter un coup d’œil hyper rapide au Traité de l' abbé Régnier et je n'y vois que l'évocation de a confusion de certains entre l'adjectif prest (→prêt) et la préposition près.


« au » ici n'indique pas la destination, comme dans
Je voyage au Mexique où j'hiverne, pour éviter le froid.

Dans cette phrase, au n'indique pas nécessairement une destination mais peut simplement indiquer un lieu. Vu le présent de j'hiverne, on est probablement déjà au Mexique quand on prononce cette phrase et dans ce cas, le Mexique n'est pas une destination. Il l'aurait indiscutablement été avec Je pars au Mexique mais pas du tout dans Je suis au Mexique.

Jupiter est près de Saturne.†
Je ne perçois aucune différence entre ceci, et 'Jupiter est auprès de Saturne.'

Il y a une grosse différence, dans la première phrase, il s'agit d'une proximité relative entre deux planètes du système solaire alors que dans la deuxième et sans autre contexte, on évoque la proximité immédiate entre deux divinités romaines. Si le contexte indique qu'on parle quand même de planètes, l'utilisation d'auprès personnifie lesdites planètes.

La maison jaune est près.‡
Je ne perçois aucune différence entre ceci, et 'La maison jaune est auprès.'

Il y a une grosse différence. La deuxième phrase n'est pas du tout idiomatique en français moderne car auprès ne peut pas terminer une phrase, étant quasiment toujours suivi de de, du, des, etc. Le registre de la première phrase est familier. Dans un registre standard ou soutenu, on dirait plus La maison jaune est proche.

Qu'est-ce que « au » signifie ?
Qu'est-ce que « au » ajoute ou contribue, le cas échéant, au « près » ?

Auprès de s'utilise essentiellement pour des êtres vivants et implique qu'il y a eu un déplacement vers ce qui suit. Je suis auprès de mon ami signifie que je me suis déplacé vers lui et que je me tiens à ses côtés. Auprès indique donc une proximité immédiate. On ne peut pas être plus auprès de ou moins auprès de, on est auprès ou on ne l'est pas. Au contraire, près est relatif et généralement quantifiable. On peut être très près, assez près, moins près, toutes expressions impossibles avec auprès.

L'absence de destination dans le tout premier point ne me semble pas entiérement indiscutable.

@Frank Pas faux. J'ai développé le sujet.
